# deployed in heroku angular 4 app with webpack but site is not start

Tags: angular, heroku, webpack

I deployed angular4 app in heroku.

But its gives error when i goes to open app. app is not build and opening.

```
2017-07-26T08:19:59.741829+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2017-07-26T08:19:59.741830+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-07-26T08:20:01.797312+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-07-26T08:20:04.642127+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-citadel-72017.herokuapp.com request_id=f96e6b85-c5d8-48f2-8099-fb8001724ef6 fwd="103.62.141.34" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=27ms status=404 bytes=360 protocol=https
2017-07-26T08:21:05.520827+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-citadel-72017.herokuapp.com request_id=b044ae56-69ad-4af1-84bf-21bf00d9706f fwd="103.62.141.34" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=360 protocol=https
2017-07-26T08:21:06.205476+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=infinite-citadel-72017.herokuapp.com request_id=5ff717d1-8ebe-403a-88e9-277478540e5e fwd="103.62.141.34" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=371 protocol=https
2017-07-26T08:34:29.309746+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-citadel-72017.herokuapp.com request_id=f8d540bd-6acf-4c24-b4cc-50de416f7810 fwd="103.62.141.34" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=360 protocol=https
2017-07-26T09:09:13.853930+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2017-07-26T09:09:13.854616+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2017-07-26T09:09:14.365925+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-07-26T09:09:14.547790+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem. if tried to build project on heroku then its gives error. its need  build on localhost after that deploye on heroku.and link it dist folder.

server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
var port = process.env.PORT || '4000';
app.set('port', port);
var server = app.listen(port);
console.log('listening on port 4000');
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular-io-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Example project from an angular.io guide.",
  "scripts": {
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --bail",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "predev": "npm run build",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "karma start karma.webpack.conf.js",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:upgrade": "tsc",
    "serve:upgrade": "http-server",
    "build:aot": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json && rollup -c rollup-config.js",
    "serve:aot": "lite-server -c bs-config.aot.json",
    "build:babel": "babel src -d src --extensions \".es6\" --source-maps",
    "copy-dist-files": "node ./copy-dist-files.js",
    "i18n": "ng-xi18n",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "ng": "ng",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
```